# PHP variable scope within classes

Tags: php, class, variables, scope, private

I am trying to make a class that simply holds and retrieves simple string variables.

Here is what i have in the User.php file (the class)

```
class User {

//private variables
private $u_s;
private $p_w;

public function _construct($u_s, $p_w){
    $this->u_s = $u_s;
    $this->p_w = md5($p_w);
}

function getUsername(){
    return $this->u_s;
}

function getPassword(){
    return $this->p_w;
}
```

}

and here is the index.php file

```
    <?php
       include("User.php");

       $u = new User("Jake", "pass");
       echo $u->getUsername() + "\n" + $u->getPassword();
    ?>
```

Why does this not work?

Answer (score 2):

You mistyped `__construct`.  There should be two underscores, not one.

Answer (score 1):

Concat char in PHP is `.` (dot), not `+` (plus) sign:

```
<?php
include("User.php");

$u = new User("Jake", "pass");
echo $u->getUsername() . "\n" . $u->getPassword();
```

And as adpalumbo said you mistyped `__construct`